# How to Mock/Patch App Engine's Oauth Decorator?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, oauth, mocking

App Engine's python client library has [made oauth flow really easy](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine) with the following decorator.

```
@decorator.oauth_required
```

But it's really not straightforward to mock/patch for unit testing.  For example in the following get handler, I need to stub out oauth decorator.

```
from auth import decorator

class ListUsersHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  @decorator.oauth_required
  def get(self):
    self.response.write(_RenderUserListTemplate())
```

I have tried something like below.

```
from mock import patch
patch('decorator.oauth_required', lambda x: x).start()
import user

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', user.ListUsersHandler)])
    self.testapp = webtest.TestApp(app)

  def testListUsersHandler(self):
    response = self.testapp.get('/')
    self.assertTrue(('list tokens' in response))
```

But, what I'm seeing this error, which doesn't seem to give much clue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user_test.py", line 44, in testAbc
    response = self.testapp.get('/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webtest/app.py", line 322, in get
    expect_errors=expect_errors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webtest/app.py", line 605, in do_request
    res = req.get_response(app, catch_exc_info=True)
  File "/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/request.py", line 1292, in send
application, catch_exc_info=True)
  File "/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/request.py", line 1269, in call_application
    return (captured[0], captured[1], app_iter, captured[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You need to provide a function that mimics what `@decorator.oauth_required` does and not just `lambda x: x`.  If you remove the decorator from your handler and run the test, does it work?

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston:  Yes, the test definitely works if the decorator is removed.  I did try to just "stub" out the decorator, but not sure how exactly to do it with python mock.  What I have below is not working

patch('decorator.oauth_required', lambda x: x).start()